# How to use video.js with create-next-app nextjs?

Tags: css, webpack, video.js, next.js

I am trying to use Video.js with create-next-app, and I am not able to load the video.js.css. this is what my component looks like.

```
import videojs from 'video.js'

import videoStyles from '../node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css'

export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // instantiate Video.js
    this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, this.props, function onPlayerReady() {
      console.log('onPlayerReady', this)
    });
  }

  // destroy player on unmount
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.dispose()
    }
  }

  // wrap the player in a div with a `data-vjs-player` attribute
  // so videojs won't create additional wrapper in the DOM
  // see https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/3856
  render() {
    return (
      <div>    
        <div data-vjs-player>
          <video ref={ node => this.videoNode = node } className="video-js"></video>
        </div>
        <style jsx>{videoStyles}</style>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am using [styled-jsx/css loader](https://github.com/coox/styled-jsx-css-loader#styled-jsxcss-loader) to load the external css file.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the next.js github [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-videojs). It should be enough to get you started.

Comment: It disappears right after rendering, I tested it without adblockers and it seems to be issue with next/react/videojs :(